# How to time camera flash with image capture?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, camera

I want to make it so that my flash will time with when I take a picture, but not sure how. I've tried to do a NSTimer and NSSleep and other ways of timing it, but because sometimes the camera takes longer to focus and take the picture, than other times, it doesn't always get the flash exactly right. How would I accomplish this?

Here is how I do the flash...

```
func toggleFlash() {
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if (device.hasTorch) {
        device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
        if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.On) {
            device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
        } else {
            device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0, error: nil)
        }
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
}
```

And here is how I take the picture...

```
func didPressTakePhoto(){

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
            (sampleBuffer, error) in

            if sampleBuffer != nil {

                var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                var dataProvider  = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                var cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)

                var image:UIImage!

                if self.camera == true {
                    image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                } else {
                    image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored)

                }

                self.tempImageView.image = image
                self.tempImageView.hidden = false

            }


        })
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `toggleFlash`, you need to set

```
device.flashMode = .On
```

You're setting the `torchMode`.

Correcting this should make the flash go off at the right time during `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection`.

Comment: Would I need to call the method only once? And if so where should I call it?

Comment: set `flashMode` during configuration, where you're setting `torchMode` now

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but could you change AVCaptureFlashModeOn to AVCaptureFlashMode.On?

Comment: sure - sorry, I'm new to swift

Comment: Yeah no problem! Thanks again. (:

Comment: You can/should simply use `device.flashMode = .On`